# Why do I get this error message when running 'yum install edb-as11-server'

Tags: installation, centos7, yum, enterprisedb

I have followed the instructions for edb installation on centos7:

1. `yum install -y https://yum.enterprisedb.com/edbrepos/edb-repo-latest.noarch.rpm`
2. edit `/etc/yum.repos.d/edb.repo` file, To enable a repository, change the value of the enabled parameter to 1 and replace the user name and password placeholders in the baseurl specification with your user name and the repository password.
3. `yum install edb-as11-server`

When I input `yum install edb-as11-server`, I get the following error message:

```
https://taohe2:KZfshrk5WpVPmshJxx@yum.enterprisedb.com/11/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 401 - Unauthorized
Trying other mirror.

 One of the configured repositories failed (EnterpriseDB Advanced Server 11 7 - x86_64),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=edbas11 ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable edbas11
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=edbas11

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=edbas11.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from edbas11: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://taohe2:KZfshrk5WpVPmshJxx@yum.enterprisedb.com/11/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 401 - Unauthorized
```

---

after that, I access the link "taohe2:KZfshrk5WpVPmshJxx@yum.enterprisedb.com/11/redhat/…" via chrome browser. It makes me to login "yum.enterprisedb.com". Then I input the right username and password which get in the page "enterprisedb.com/user". But it doesn't work, I can't login.

Comment: check you can login via a browser & see if you can find the path to the xml file. that will help rule out some basic remote issue (like the file is broken/missing)

Comment: It seems that you might have the wrong password?  You should be able to log into enterprisedb.com and get the correct password: https://www.enterprisedb.com/user

Comment: I access the link "https://taohe2:KZfshrk5WpVPmshJxx@yum.enterprisedb.com/11/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml" via chrome browser. It makes me to login "https://yum.enterprisedb.com". Then I input the right username and password which get in the page "https://www.enterprisedb.com/user". But it doesn't work, I can't login.

Comment: Please email EDB Support at support@enterprisedb.com, and I'll help you (just mention my username here).

Comment: Just for the record, we were able to resolve the issue via EDB support (was a Yum repository issue)